# Searching one model by another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sunspot

My application consists of a drink model

```
class Drink < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :recipe_steps, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :ingredients, through: :recipe_steps
end
```

An ingredient model

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :recipe_steps
end
```

how would I go about having it so when a user searches an ingredient that it returns all of the drinks with that ingredient?

Additional information: I'm currently using sunspot/solr for my searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in your `Ingredient` model you'd need this line:

```
has_many :drinks, through: :recipe_steps
```

To define the `has_many, through:` relationship. Make sure that `RecipeStep` has these lines, too:

```
belongs_to :ingredient
belongs_to :drink
```

Then you can do something like in the `DrinksController`:

```
def search
  term = params[:search]
  ingredient = Ingredient.where(:name => term)
  @drinks = Ingredient.find(ingredient).drinks
end
```

And your form should look something like this:

```
<%= form_for @drink, :url => { :action => "search" } do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :search %>
<% end %>
```

I don't know all your names for everything but this should get you going.

Comment: Would I put the search method inside my drink controller? And how should my form look to make it filter this? Currently my search form consists of a text field with params[:search]

Comment: This is really helpful... I have been on this for the past 4 days.. The last question I have is how do I have my table that looks at my index action in my controller for @drinks use the drinks from the search action?

Comment: So you want a table that displays the search results? Make a view called `search.html.erb` in the `drinks` folder, a route for it in routes.rb (i.e., `get "/drinks/search/:search" => "drinks#search", :as => :drinks_search`), then add a `redirect_to` in the method to `drinks_search_path`. Then in the view you can do something like `@drinks.each do |drink|`, etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Following should work fine:

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :recipe_steps
  has_many :drinks, through: :recipe_steps
end
```